# Why aren't rudders automatic?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, general-aviation, rudder

Why aren't rudder pedals automatic or connected with ailerons to keep the nose of the aircraft coordinated with the turn its entering? Wouldn't this make for an easier and smoother to operate aircraft?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74475/62)

Comment: Related: [Do modern aircraft require rudder input in order to perform a coordinated turn?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51316/do-modern-aircraft-require-rudder-input-in-order-to-perform-a-coordinated-turn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of yawing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/whats-the-purpose-of-yawing)

Comment: IMHO, this is a duplicate, in that knowing why one needs to control yaw also explains why linking rudder and aileron is not something you want in every airplane. The answer to this question is also found in the Q&A mentioned above, as well as https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24051/can-perfect-turn-coordination-automation-be-achieved-by-linking-rudder-to-ailero, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/why-dont-all-ga-aircraft-have-yaw-dampers, and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27823/why-is-using-opposite-rudder-and-aileron-necessary-in-left-turn-for-coordin

Comment: The answers, all described in the duplicate and related posts, come down to: 1) it's not feasible to include such a feature in all planes, especially smaller/less-expensive ones, 2) it's not desirable to always remain coordinated, and 3) coordination in an airplane involves more than just a direct, proportional input of rudder along with aileron (this is closely related to the first point)

Comment: Also related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3864/did-wolfgang-langewiesche-ever-change-his-mind-about-rudder-pedals.

Comment: Re "Why aren't rudder pedals automatic or connected with ailerons" -- Well, some are-- e.g. Piper Tri Pacer (connected to ailerons w/ bungees or springs), Ercoupe (no separate rudder pedals at all)

Comment: @quiet flyer: That makes me wonder how you steer an Ercoupe when taxiing.

Comment: @jamesqf-- nosewheel steering is connected to yoke, I believe.

Comment: @quiet flyer: That must be fun when landing & taxiing in strong crosswinds.